# RenderScript: Unable to open shared library: (null)

Tags: android, renderscript, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I wrote a simple application that uses RenderScript to change the camera's preview. There were no issues with other devices except `Honor 6X` and `Nexus 6p` both with Android 7.0 where the camera preview only shows a black screen.

The error messages are as follows:

```
V/RenderScript: Successfully loaded runtime: libRSDriver_adreno.so
E/RenderScript: Unable to open shared library (/data/user_de/0/com.my.test/code_cache/com.android.renderscript.cache/librs.invert.so): (null)
V/RenderScript: Invoking /system/bin/bcc with args '/system/bin/bcc -unroll-runtime -scalarize-load-store -rs-global-info -rs-global-info-skip-constant -o invert -output_path /data/user_de/0/com.my.test/code_cache/com.android.renderscript.cache -bclib /system/lib/libclcore.bc -mtriple armv7-none-linux-gnueabi -O 3 -load libbccQTI.so -fPIC -embedRSInfo /data/user_de/0/com.my.test/code_cache/com.android.renderscript.cache/invert.bc -build-checksum abadcafe'
V/RenderScript: Invoking /system/bin/ld.mc with args '/system/bin/ld.mc -shared -nostdlib /system/lib/libcompiler_rt.so -mtriple=armv7-none-linux-gnueabi --library-path=/system/vendor/lib --library-path=/system/lib -lRSDriver_adreno -lm -lc /data/user_de/0/com.my.test/code_cache/com.android.renderscript.cache/invert.o -o /data/user_de/0/com.my.test/code_cache/com.android.renderscript.cache/librs.invert.so'
```

My RenderScript file is also the same as to:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#writing-an-rs-kernel

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.my.test)

uchar4 RS_KERNEL invert(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
  uchar4 out = in;

  out.r = 255 - in.r;
  out.g = 255 - in.g;
  out.b = 255 - in.b;
  return out;
}
```

**EDIT:**

The camera preview only shows a black screen on the mentioned devices.

Comment: I think it's normal, is your app working? Don't forget #pragma rs_fp_relaxed

Comment: no, it's just showing a black screen.

Comment: Did you try it on just a loaded Bitmap as input? May not affect anything, but try setting out.a = 255 just to be sure alpha is not 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue with `RenderScript` rather with the Camera or my implementation, see [Camera onPreviewFrame not called on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053848/camera-onpreviewframe-not-called-on-some-devices) as I have found out that some devices do not call the `onPreviewFrame` which led to this issue.