# Camera onPreviewFrame not called on some devices

Tags: android, android-camera, android-canvas

I am expecting the LogCat to be logging `#onPreviewFrame()` multiple times, but it only works on selected devices like:

- Samsung Galaxy S6 (7.0)
- Samsung Galaxy S6 (6.0.1)
- LG Leon (5.0.1)

But does not on the following devices:

- LG G4 (6.0)
- Huawei 6X (7.0)
- Nexus 6P (7.0)

Below is the code snippet:

```
public CameraSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
  super(context, set);
  Log.d(TAG, "CameraSurfaceView(context, set)");

  // Get the Surface Holder
  this.holder = this.getHolder();
  this.holder.addCallback(this);
  this.holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  try {
    // Turn on the Camera
    this.camera = Camera.open();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(TAG, "#surfaceCreated() error=" + ex.getMessage(), ex);
  }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
  Log.d(TAG, "#surfaceChanged()");

  if (holder.getSurface() == null) {
    // preview surface does not exist
    return;
  }
  if (camera == null) {
    // camera does not exist
    return;
  }

  // This allows us to make our own draw calls to this canvas
  this.setWillNotDraw(false);
  // Initialize canvas variables
  previewPaint = new Paint();
  // Initialize preview variables
  deviceWidth = width;
  deviceHeight = height;
  Camera.Size previewSize = this.camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
  previewWidth = previewSize.width;
  previewHeight = previewSize.height;
  previewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewWidth, previewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

  // Initialize Scale Variables
  previewScaleMatrix = new Matrix();
  previewScaleMatrix.setScale(deviceWidth / (float) previewWidth,
      deviceHeight / (float) previewHeight, deviceWidth / 2.0f, deviceHeight / 2.0f);

  // Initialize RenderScript variables
  rs = RenderScript.create(getContext());

  // RenderScript YUV to RGB
  yuvToRgbScript = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
  Type.Builder previewRgbaType =
      new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs)).setX(previewWidth).setY(previewHeight);
  yuvToRgbOut = Allocation.createTyped(rs, previewRgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

  // RenderScript Invert
  invertScript = new ScriptC_invert(rs);
  invertOut = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvToRgbOut.getType(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

  // Set color effect to none
  parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NONE);
  camera.setParameters(parameters);

  // Set the preview callback
  Log.d(TAG, "#surfaceChanged() camera.setPreviewCallback()");
  camera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      Log.d(TAG, "#onPreviewFrame()");
    }
  });

  // Start the camera preview
  Log.d(TAG, "#surfaceChanged() camera.startPreview()");
  camera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // Surface will be destroyed when replaced with a new screen
  // Always make sure to release the Camera instance
  if (camera != null) {
    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
  }
}
```

My LogCat displays as follows:

```
D/CameraSurfaceView: #surfaceChanged()
D/CameraSurfaceView: #surfaceChanged() camera.setPreviewCallback()
D/CameraSurfaceView: #surfaceChanged() camera.startPreview()
```

The `ScriptC_invert` is from the `RenderScript` sample in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#writing-an-rs-kernel

And even if I remove all RenderScript stuff, the same problem.

I've also tried the following:

- [Camera onPreviewFrame not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042377/camera-onpreviewframe-not-called)
- [Android onPreviewFrame is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412618/android-onpreviewframe-is-not-called)

**NOTE:**

One fix would need a `camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder)` in my `surfaceChanged()` method. But this will create another issue for me since I would need to do a `holder.lockCanvas()` in `onPreviewFrame()` and encounter the following exception:

```
E/SurfaceHolder: Exception locking surface
                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                     at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
                     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:264)
                     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.internalLockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:842)
                     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.lockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:830)
                     at com.arcanys.ar.CameraSurfaceView.onPreviewFrame(CameraSurfaceView.java:204)
```

There might be some things that I've missed or misconfigured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the time being, I haven't found a fix for this issue, rather I have a workaround.

Since we cannot use both `camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder)` and `camera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback)` at the same time expect to use the `surfaceHolder.lockCanvas()` in `onPreviewFrame()` for some devices, I have transferred my preview to another `SurfaceView` and handle the `onPreviewFrame()` from there and use its own `SufraceHolder`.

Comment: This is a correct workaround. [setPreviewDisplay or setPreviewTexture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752454/setpreviewdisplay-vs-setpreviewtexture) is compulsory in Android, but some devices don't enforce it.

Comment: BTW, consider switching to the **camera2** API unless most of your target devices are below Lollipop. And if you decide to stay with the *deprecated* Camera API, make sure you open the camera in a separate Handler thread (so that Camera.open() and callbacks do not cause congestion on the UI thread).

Comment: @AlexCohn thank you for your advice. Yes, I'm also targeting pre-lollipop devices this is why I'm still using the deprecated camera API.

Comment: you can use `camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder)` and `camera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback)` at the same time, what are talking about?.. you can't use`camera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);` and `camera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());` at the same time